# get data from Navigation Activity in Navigation library

Tags: android, navigation, android-architecture-components

I'm using Navigation library from Architecture Components where in MainActivity I setup navigation and Toolbar as main Toolbar for whole app. In navigation.xml file I setup app:startDestination for one of fragments. Is it possible to get data about Toolbar which is lockated in MainActivity while I am already in launched fragment?

**MainActivity:**

```
ublic class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private NavigationActivityBinding binding;

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.navigation_activity);
    NavHostFragment hostFragment =
            (NavHostFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.my_nav_host_fragment);
    setSupportActionBar(binding.toolbar);

    NavController navController = hostFragment.getNavController();
    setupActionBar(navController);
    setupBottomNavigation(navController);
}

private void setupBottomNavigation(NavController navController) {
    NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(binding.bottomNavView, navController);
}

private void setupActionBar(NavController navController) {
    NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, null);
}}
```

**navigation.xml:**

```
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
app:startDestination="@+id/launcher_home">
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/launcher_home"
    android:name="josiak.android.example.cryptocurrency.charts.ui.CryptocurrencyMainList"
    android:label="fragment_cryptocurrency_main_list"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_cryptocurrency_main_list" />
```

Answer (score 1):

When I tried to `((MainActivity).getActivity()).getSupportActionBar()` in fragment lifecycle method `onActivityCreated()` it returned null value for `getHeight()` but when I tried to do `((MainActivity).getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().getHeight()` when I click button/menu item, it works. Seems like I can get height of action bar only after fragment is activated.

Answer (score 1):

You can add addOnNavigatedListener inside your activity, and based on current destination do something with toolbar. If you want to pass some data to current fragment, you can use viewmodel attached to activity, and set parameters/states, to which fragment is listening.

```
findNavController(nav_host_fragment).addOnNavigatedListener { controller, 
destination ->
    when(destination.id) {
        R.id.destination1 -> {
            //Do something with your toolbar
        }
        R.id.destination2 -> {
            //Do something with your toolbar
        }

 }
}
```

Comment: If I will need to do something more complex then I'll give it a try with viewmodel attached to activity, thank you for your answer.